# what does `ioctl` do in `struct tty_driver`?

Tags: linux-kernel, driver

What does `ioctl` do in the structure `struct tty_driver`?

I know the `ioctl()` function provides the means to control the hardware (Keyboard, Mouse, Print) but for example a driver to control the leds on the keyboard I think that the ioctl is more than enough to do this task...

So why I need a tty_driver? I know tty_driver is a struct

P.D I've never tried to program a Device Driver. I've only read a bit of code in some books.

Comment: ioctl is _device specific_, that's why it should be in a structure that defines that particular device. Is that what you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

When developing a new driver, the `struct tty_driver` structure is used to register a tty_driver (using `tty_register_driver()` [1](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L3337)). This code creates a new device file and set the file operations to some tty specific functions.

The ioctl entry in the newly created file operations is set to `tty_ioctl()` [2](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L2719) which after handling some of the basic commands will call the `.ioctl` function set in the `struct tty_operations` [3](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L2848) referenced in the `struct tty_driver`.

By defining `ioctl` (note that it is checked if it is not `NULL` in [3](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c#L2848)) the developer can implement ioctl commands specific to its device or simply be notified of some other standard commands.